# How do I use get audio from multiple screens using split-screen in Filmora

Tags: audio

I am using Filmora to create videos and would like to have several videos put together via split-screen.  I am able to do this, but I would like the audio from each of those split screens to come through.  It appears that Filmora is only allowing audio to come from one of the videos.  Is there a way to have it come from multiple videos simultaneously?

Comment: No. It is limited to one. It is hell trying to sync video up, let alone sound.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do it is by using PIP function, but it looks bad and won't allow you to split evenly and symmetrically like the split screen functions.  And Synching is nearly impossible, or I should say, cumbersome.